# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode

Tengo la siguiente función para llamar una URL que se encuentra en un REST desde Swift 2, pero cuando envío valores con espacio en el NSURL me aparece el siguiente error:

> **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

```
class func getApi(urlWithArgs: String?) -> NSMutableURLRequest {
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlWithArgs!)!
    let resquest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)

    return resquest
}
```

¿Qué tengo mal para que aparezca ese error únicamente cuando envío valores con un espacio? Ejemplo, envío un nombre: "pepito perez". ¿Por qué si envío "pepitoperez" funciona?

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que las URLs con un espacio no son válidas, y `NSURL(string: urlWithArgs!)` te esté devolviendo `nil`.

Si tu URL tiene espacios (u otros caracteres que no son válidos en una URL), además deberías "escapear" el `String`.

La forma correcta de implementar esta función sería:

```
class func getApi(urlWithArgs: String?) -> NSMutableURLRequest? {
    guard urlWithArgs != nil else {
        return nil
    }

    var request: NSMutableURLRequest? = nil
    if let escapedStr = urlWithArgs!.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet()) {
        if let url = NSURL(string: escapedStr) {
            request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        }
    }

    return request
}
```

Comment: Modifique la funcion como me dijo pero en el siguiente metodo me aparece el mismo errorÑ fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value  class func authenticateUser(user: String, password: String) -> NSMutableURLRequest {
        let request = self.getApi(Helpers.REQUESTAPIURL + "/usuarioLogin?correo=\(user)&pwd=\(password)")
        
        return request!
    }

Comment: @AndresGuillermoCastellanosA Creo que tendrías que buscar información sobre cómo funcionan los Optional en Swift...

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda